# joomla 3 smart search not indexing articles

Tags: php, joomla, full-text-search

I have joomla 3.x site which is in unicode (Bengali). I want to implement `Full-Text` search on my site. As far I know joomla smart search is full text search. However when I run indexer from backend its showing "success" but nothing happened. In fact no content (articles) are being indexed.

I have seen console, no `JS` error there. What wrong?

[image: Indexing showing success]

Comment: Do you have access to the command line? In my experience sometimes smart search dies during indexing when it hits an error/ problem text.  However it is hard to find the actual article that has the error. If you run the command line indexer you actually get the error messages.  In fact I'd just do it locally on a backup of your database if you can't do it on your host. There are problems when there are diacritical marks,  so that would be my bet.

Comment: I have access CLI but no idea how to index through CLI in Joomla and sphinx as well

Comment: There is a file indexer.php in the cli folder.  Just run that as is `php indexer.php`.  That should give you the index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the smart search content plugins are enabled in the plugin manager.

Comment: confirmed. plugin enabled

Comment: There are multiple plugins, which have you enabled?